# Ошибка при запуске приложения с ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard

Ошибка при запуске приложения:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't
>   write
>   [D:\project1\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar]
>   (Can't read
>   [D:\project1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\25.1.0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
>   (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$p.class
>   == classes.jar:android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.class]))
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
>
> > Job failed, see logs for details

Вот Build.gradle

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 25
>       buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
>       defaultConfig {
>           applicationId "com.dreamappstudio.project"
>           minSdkVersion 14
>           targetSdkVersion 25
>           versionCode 1
>           versionName "1.0"
>           multiDexEnabled true
>       }
>
> ```
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled true
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
>                 'proguard-rules.pro'
>     }
>     debug {
>         minifyEnabled true
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
>                 'proguard-rules.pro'
>     }
> } } repositories {
> flatDir {
>     dirs 'libs'
> } }
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>
> ```
> compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.2.5'
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
> compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
> compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0') {
>     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
> }
> compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
> compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
> compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
> compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.32'
> compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
> compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
>
>
>
> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
> compile name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
> compile name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar' }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка из-за `recycler.`
Попробуйте так

```
compile('замените на вашу версию recycler') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Вставил в dependencies  ваш код, всеравно получается тоже самое